# Missing definition for "Days"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, days

im trying to highlight the rows where the paid date is expired or it has 30 days to be expired.
when i build this it says it `... does not contain Definition for the ".Days"`.

im new to this please help

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    int daysLeft = (item.MembershipType.PaidDate - DateTime.Today).Days;

    string style = daysLeft <= 30 ? "background-color:Red" : null;

    <tr style="@style">

        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplierName)

        </td>

        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MembershipType.PaidDate)

        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `PaidDate` ?

Comment: the type of PaidDate Is DateTime

Comment: Please explain with more clarity, what exactly you are looking for!!

Comment: i am trying to highlight a row if the date is expired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `PaidDate` is `nullable DateTime` i.e `DateTime?`, it will return `Nullable<TimeSpan>` object which does not contain definition of `Days` so thats why you are getting this error, you need to check if it is not null then cast it to `DateTime`:

```
if(item.MembershipType.PaidDate.HasValue)
{
DateTime PaidDate = (DateTime)item.MembershipType.PaidDate;
int daysLeft = (PaidDate - DateTime.Today).Days;
}
```

or you can cast it in the same line from `Nullable<TimeSpan>` to `TimeSpan`:

```
int daysLeft = ((TimeSpan)(item.MembershipType.PaidDate - DateTime.Today)).Days;
```